# iOS post notification when device connects to wi-fi

Tags: ios, networking, notifications

Is there a way for me to automatically post a notification when the device connects to a wi-fi or maybe a mobile data network?

I was thinking that, when the connection happens, to use this in my application delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"connectedToNetwork"
 object:nil];
```

and in my class to catch this notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doSomething)
                                             name:@"connectedToNetwork"
                                           object:nil];
```

I am using Reachability to see if the device is connected to the internet, but this is not what I want. I want some notification automatically to be called when the device connects to wi-fi or to a mobile network. I don't care if through that network the internet is reachable, I just need to be notified when the connection occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// tell the reachability that we DONT want to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
reach.reachableOnWWAN = NO;

// here we set up a NSNotification observer. The Reachability that caused the notification
// is passed in the object parameter
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[reach startNotifier]
```